# Splash screen status bar color on Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I want to customize the color of the status bar that is shown during the splash screen.

What used to work on Windows Phone 8.1 seems to be broken on Windows 10.
I use a splash screen PNG and set the `Splash Screen Background color` in my package manifest to the same color that the PNG.

Here is the result with a Windows Phone 8.1 app running on a WP8.1 device:

[image]

And the **same app** running on Windows 10:

[image]

It's the same with Windows 10 apps, the status bar is always black.
Is there a way to have a colored status bar on Windows 10 Mobile?

Comment: @JustinXL that answer doesn't apply for splash screens, right?

Comment: Actually, I just compiled a project with .NET Native and ran it on a reasonably high end phone and saw the same black taskbar above. Good find! This is going to be annoying...

Comment: Recommendation is to not use Splash screens any more. If you need some branding, use a page and throw in some animation to make it snazy

Comment: @ShawnKendrot Where does that recommendation come from? Here is what is indicated on MSDN: "Every Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app must have a splash screen, which consists of a splash screen image and a background color." (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465338.aspx)

Comment: I thought it was stated at build, but maybe not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this was a bug in the preview builds of Windows 10 mobile.
It's now fixed (build 10.0.10586.11).

Answer (score -3):

Actually you can do this so easy! First of all, verify is this API is present.

Look this:

```
if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))
            {
                var statusBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
                statusBar.BackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent;
                statusBar.ForegroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.Red;
            }
```

Comment: So when would you call this to modify the status bar of a view that's not even initialized?

Comment: Yes, the question is not about the status bar when the app is running, but when the app is launching (during the splash screen).

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work, at least in this case. All methods for modifying the style of the StatusBar are executed after the splash screen is dismissed.